# rEFInd - can boot to Mac Recovery or Ubuntu, but shuts down after loading bar for MacOS

Tags: startup, recovery, efi

I have rEFInd installed on my 2015 rMBP - I can access the boot menu for rEFInd (although sometimes this doesn't appear / runs very slowly), and all the right options are there, but when I select MacOS it shows the Apple logo / loading bar, but turns off once the loading bar has completed.

I can (sometimes) get to the Apple Recovery OS, where everything works as it should but I can't work out how to get back to the point where I can boot into MacOS. If necessary, I don't mind completely removing the Ubuntu partition but I would prefer not to have to restore / reformat the MacOS partition as there are important files I haven't backed up.

Comment: Just to add, I've tried all the recommended key-combos at startup (Recovery, Internet Recovery, Safe Mode, Resetting NVRAM)

Comment: Why are you using rEFInd? The current version of Ubuntu does not require rEFInd. You can select Ubuntu from the Startup Manager. Perhaps you have other operating systems installed? Also, is macOS installed to a JHFS+, Core Storage or APFS partition?